# How to compare two variable values of the same method

Tags: java, selenium

There are two methods of same class .I want to  compare two variables value by using assertion  .

here are the two methods

//Method 1

```
public void Edit_window() throws InterruptedException {

        collection_title.clear();

//        driver.wait(2000);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
         Date date = new Date();
        collection_title.sendKeys(dateFormat.format(date));


    }
```

//Method 2

```
public void name_collection()
    {
        String updated_title=col_title.getText() ;

        System.out.println("the title eof the collectio is " + updated_title) ;

        System.out.println("the value is" + date) ;
    }
```

So if you can see there is one variable "date " and it contains the current date. I want to that variable value and compare with the variable value "updated_title" which is defined in the method 2 . Any input please !

Answer (score 1):

You can basically change the return type of the methods to String type and then add assertion. Sample below:

```
public String Edit_window() throws InterruptedException {

        collection_title.clear();

//        driver.wait(2000);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
         Date date = new Date();
        collection_title.sendKeys(dateFormat.format(date));
return dateFormat.format(date);
    }


public String name_collection()
    {
        String updated_title=col_title.getText() ;

        System.out.println("the title eof the collectio is " + updated_title) ;

        System.out.println("the value is" + date) ;
return date;
    }
```

//And then for assertion you can basically: `Assert.asserEquals(classObject.Edit_window(), classObject.name_collection);`

Answer (score 0):

Hope the solution provided by the Mrunal is works for you. I will suggest you to create a public class and store the Reusable values such as id, email, autogenerated numbers etc. So that you should be able to access anywhere from your framework.

we can't say that always we will only do the comparison in the same class. So please try to create the class as below and use it to store the values.

```
public class Repovalues {

private string id;

 public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```